# $\sin(x)$ meets Rotating Plane

Tags: geometry

A forward moving sine wave passes through a uniformly rotating plane orthogonal to it, what will the resulting image on the plane look like?

Comment: uniformly rotating orthogonal to the direction of the sine wave's forward motion.

Comment: You should try to explain what you mean.  As it stands, you could easily be talking about the paths with the parametric form $x = \sin(t)\cos(kt), \quad y = \sin(t)\sin(kt)$, which to me just looks like the "spirograph" type pictures.  Without at least saying something about $k$ (how the angular speed of rotation relates to the frequency), no single answer is possible.

Comment: is there an equation or a mathematical description for the resulting spirograph?

Comment: A forward moving sine wave should be give by an equation similar to $y=A\sin(\omega t -kx)$. Also the notion of a plane "orthogonal" to the sine wave should be given, as well as the notion of "rotating plane".

Comment: Let's use Cartesian coordinates $(x, y, z)$ with the wave along the $x$-axis. It might help to edit the question to clarify: 1. Is the wave traveling or standing? 2. Is the wave transverse (along the $z$-axis, say) or longitudinal? 3. Is the rotating plane the $(x, y)$-plane, the $(y, z)$-plane, or what? 4. About what axis is the plane rotating? 5. What does _the resulting image on the plane_ mean? My reading was, the wave is longitudinal, the plane is $(x, y)$ revolving about $z$. Brian's interpretation seems to use the $(y, z)$-plane revolving about $x$. <> Anyway, these items are ambiguous.